# Yeoman: Is it possible to create multistep prompts?

Tags: generator, yeoman, prompt, yo

Is it possible to create promps that dipends on previous answers in yeoman generator-generator?

example:

```
languages supported?
  [ ] en
  [ ] it
  [ ] es
  [ ] de
  ...
```

and then ask if 'en' is selected

```
translation of "this thing" in en: ____
```

and if 'it' is selected

```
translation of "this thing" in it: ____
```

etc?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman is only JavaScript. So yes, it is totally possible to use the answer to launch a new prompt session from the callback.

Inquirer.js documentation even have an example: https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/master/examples/nested-call.js

Comment: thank you Simon Boudrias!

I've tryed writhing this script : https://gist.github.com/matteo-bombelli/83ce4d7f03053cf1aed6b7480df99b31

but I've got a problem with the promises: the second one seems to be executed after the "end" call.

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I'd encourage you to read the Promise documentation. Specifically on how `then` is working https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. I'm looking at it.

Comment: This is a bit late, but @MatteoBombelli, the reason the second one ends after the entire generator has run is because you are returning the "outer" promise as the return value. What Simon was trying to get you to see is that if you return a Promise from a `then` callback, the outer promise will inherit the state of the inner promise. So you need to add a return statement at line 38 (and subsequently need to move your `this.props` assignment since it will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little (maybe hacky) solution:

https://gist.github.com/matteo-bombelli/f4c8bc17ec83a12cb0de058016aa1f8f#file-index-js-L51

Instead of nesting it inside the promise (wich has geven me problems with the promises timing), I've put it into another task that will be grouped in the [default group](http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html) which is after the prompting.

But I don't like this solution very much. If the use of "then" and the promise can be done would prefer that one.

Thank You!